# No speed gain from Numba optimized functions

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization, numba

I have written some code that computes flexural moments imposed by different trucks for a bridge with 300 ft length. Truck data are contained in two lists: `ax_list` and `sp_list`, which are the axle weights and axle spacings, respectively.

There is nothing much to the code, however, this needs to be repeated for millions of different truck types, and I am trying to optimize my code, which takes real long time when the actual data size set is concerned.

I tried using Numba to see if I can get any speed gains, but it did not change the execution time, whether I add Numba `@jit` decorators for each function or not. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be welcome! I also included code to generate representative pseudo data for 1000 records below:

```
import random
from numba import jit
import numpy as np
from __future__ import division

#Generate Random Data Set

ax_list=[]
sp_list=[]

for i in xrange(1000):
    n = random.randint(3,10)
    ax = []
    sp = [0]
    for i in xrange(n):
        a = round(random.uniform(8,32),1)
        ax.append(a)
    for i in xrange(n-1):
        s = round(random.uniform(4,30), 1)
        sp.append(s)
    ax_list.append(ax)
    sp_list.append(sp)

#Input Parameters
L=300
step_size=4
cstep_size=4
moment_list=[]

@jit
#Simple moment function
def Moment(x):
    if x<L/2.0:
        return 0.5*x
    else:
        return 0.5*(L-x)

#Attempt to vectorize the Moment function, hoping for speed gains
vectMoment = np.vectorize(Moment,otypes=[np.float],cache=False)

@jit
#Truck movement function that uses the vectorized Moment function above
def SimpleSpanMoment(axles, spacings, step_size):
    travel = L + sum(spacings)
    spacings=list(spacings)
    maxmoment = 0
    axle_coords =(0-np.cumsum(spacings))
    while np.min(axle_coords) < L:
        axle_coords = axle_coords + step_size
        moment_inf = np.where((axle_coords >= 0) & (axle_coords <=L), vectMoment(axle_coords), 0)
        moment = sum(moment_inf * axles)
        if maxmoment < moment:
            maxmoment = moment
    return maxmoment
```

Then to run the loop for 1000 times:

```
%%timeit
for i in xrange(len(ax_list)):
    moment_list.append(np.around(SimpleSpanMoment(ax_list[i], sp_list[i], step_size),1))
```

yields:

```
1 loop, best of 3: 2 s per loop
```

I also tried declaring types in jit decorators, but still no change in results.

`@jit('f8(f8)')` and `@jit('f8(f8[:],f8[:],f8)')`, respectively for the two functions.

Comment: It seems like you're tossing all tools at the problem. I suggest a more systematic approach; try profiling. Python profiling is very simple. It will show you the bottle necks, so you can strategically utilize the tools you know.

The reason this is better is of course time. I realize there's no way to learn all optimization tools in the world. So you find the slowest part of your code and learn a tiny bit about a new optimizer that works to solve this specific issue!

Comment: I figured out Numba keeps all veriables as python objects in the second function, instead of typing them. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic problem is that when you use `nb.jit` and it encounters things that it cannot compile down to native code, it uses `object mode` instead, which can be slow. You can see this if you specify `nopython=True` as an argument to most numba decorators/functions. Then you'll get an error if numba can't explicitly type a variable or doesn't know how to otherwise translate a function. Here is a version that I believe produces the same results as your original functions. On my machine your code takes about 2.7 seconds to run. The optimized one below that runs completely in `nopython` mode takes about 50 miliseconds (an ~50x speedup):

```
@nb.vectorize(nopython=True)
#Simple moment function
def vectMoment2(x):
    if x<L/2.0:
        return 0.5*x
    else:
        return 0.5*(L-x)

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
#Truck movement function that uses the vectorized Moment function above
def SimpleSpanMoment2(axles, spacings, step_size):
    travel = L + np.sum(spacings)
    maxmoment = 0
    axle_coords = -np.cumsum(spacings)

    moment_inf = np.empty_like(axles)
    while np.min(axle_coords) < L:
        axle_coords = axle_coords + step_size
        y = vectMoment2(axle_coords)

        for k in range(y.shape[0]):
            if axle_coords[k] >=0 and axle_coords[k] <= L:
                moment_inf[k] = y[k]
            else:
                moment_inf[k] = 0.0

        moment = np.sum(moment_inf * axles)
        if maxmoment < moment:
            maxmoment = moment
    return maxmoment
```

and then timing via:

```
%%timeit
for i in xrange(len(ax_list)):
    moment_list2.append(np.around(SimpleSpanMoment2(np.array(ax_list[i]), np.array(sp_list[i]), step_size),1))
```

Take a look at the docs for what Numba supports in `nopython` mode:

- http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html
- http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html

Note, you can use `np.where` inside of numba function in `nopython` mode, but the 3rd argument has to be an array (e.g. `np.zeros_like(moment_inf)`) instead of an integer. I found that it's about 2x slower than the way I coded the function above where I just explicitly loop over the array.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is indeed the solution I was looking for. My whole code has 20 or so functions like the example above. I moved the whole code to Numba, and gained x40 ~ x50 speedup over all.